# How to get Interection type in Multi-Channel Funnel

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using RGA library from r to get data from the Google Analytics api.
In the GA interface, under Top Conversion Paths, I can see if each interaction was a click or impression (for Display). I am also able to select the specific interaction type through the 'Interaction Type:' dropdown.

However, I can't find how to add Interaction Type (impression/click) into my api call.

```
ga_data <- get_mcf(profileId="ga:XXXXXXXXXX", start.date = "2017-02-01", end.date = "2017-02-02",
               metrics = "mcf:totalConversions",
               dimensions = "mcf:basicChannelGroupingPath",
               filter = "mcf:conversionGoalNumber==006 || mcf:conversionGoalNumber==009)",
               samplingLevel = "HIGHER_PRECISION")
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: maybe add display channel to dimensions?

Comment: he's already in basicChannelGroupingPath. for ex one of result lines: Paid Search > Display > (unavailable) > Display > Organic Search > Paid Search, But I need to see something like we can extrat from interface: Paid Search > Display (impression) > (unavailable) > Display > Organic Search > Paid Search

Answer (score 1):

Interaction type is unfortunately not yet in the schema in the MCF API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/